# How to recursively look up value from within a join after getting value from another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

T1

```
pid     reason     cid
-----------------------
1        aaa       C1
1        bbb       C2
```

I want to select the `cid` with greatest value to get to the reason. I can select the greatest `cid` like so:

```
SELECT MAX(TRIM('C' from cid)) AS id
FROM T1
```

However when I try to introduce the `reason` column like so:

```
 SELECT reason, MAX(TRIM('C' from cid)) AS id
 FROM T1
 GROUP BY reason
```

I get the following result:

```
reason      cid
---------------
aaa         1
bbb         2
```

I only need the `reason` where `cid` equals `2`.

To add more complexity I only want to extract the `reason` field from the greatest `cid` from within a `LEFT` join.

```
select t2.* 
  from t2 
  left join (select to pick `reason` with greatest `cid`) 
    on t2.pid = t1.pid
```

How do I take the greatest value in `cid` from T1, look up the `reason` field and pull it into T1 via the left join?

Comment: Note that `MAX(trim('C' from cid))` is most probably not doing what you think it does. It compares the numbers as strings, so if you have `'C2'` und `'C10'` your expression would return `'2'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for the clarification that helped alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `reason` isn't used at all in your final query, but maybe that's just a typo?

Use limit 1 to get the last row:

```
SELECT pid, reason, cid FROM T1 order by cid DESC limit 1;
```

Then, your final query could be something like this:

```
select t2.*, reason
from t2 
left join (select pid, reason FROM T1 order by cid DESC limit 1) as sub on sub.pid = t2.pid;
```

If cid is not unique, you may want to add more columns to the order by clause to make your result deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT reason, MAX(trim('C' from cid)) as id
FROM T1
GROUP BY reason
HAVING MAX(trim('C' from cid)) = 2;
```

Comment: This isnt working for me, because the solution needs to be scalable. I can not have static like having =2. I want to check maximum cid for every pid. Does that make sense? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The query would be

```
SELECT reason,
       trim('C' from cid)
FROM t1
ORDER BY trim('C' from cid) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

I cannot answer the part about the outer join, because the requirement is too vague.